# How to run codes after the Ionic App has exited?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 2 to develop my **Android** project. I need to send a notification while have detected my iBeacon devices nearby **even if my App has been exited**.

The following plugins does not work for me:

[Background mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode): Works while App has been put in background. But what I need is to send notifications while the App has been killed.

[Bgs](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core): Doesn't work for me. The founder didn't try Ionic 2 project, so that he cannot figure out what may be the problem. But I do create a project [here](https://github.com/Voyager2718/test_cordova_background_service).

**Just hope someone can tell me if it's possible to create an independent background service to retrive data.** So that I can stop wasting time.

Comment: What is exactly the issue with bgs ? Have you looked at other questions ? It has been asked several times.

Comment: @e666 I asked the author of the plugin, but he told me that he have never try Ionic 2, so he doesn't know what would be the problem.

Comment: @e666 https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/65 Here's my issue.

Comment: @e666 Actually is that all our background actions have to be written in Java ? Because I suppose that TypeScript in Ionic 2 calls Cordova, and Cordova call related Java functions. I suppose it's impossible to write background actions in TypeScript, isn't it? Finally, pay attention that *background* means when we exit the application.